# Payment options with Magento for India-based transactions

Tags: magento, e-commerce, payment-gateway, oscommerce, zen-cart

I'm trying to choose an e-Commerce platform, and am leaning towards Magento.

I would need to accept online payment from Indian customers - would this be possible with Magento?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento supports a ton of payment gateways.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/50-payment-gateways-now-supported-in-magento/

You shouldn't have a problem finding one that accepts payments from India.